# Different result while updating value at a given index in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I created a 2 dimensional list in python using 
`c=[[0]*5]*3` 
and tried to update the value at 
`c[1][4]=c[0][3]+1`

but the value get updated at every 4th index of each row.
I am not understanding why it happened?

```
>>> c=[[0]*5]*3

>>> c 

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] , [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

>>> c[1][4]=c[0][3]+1

>>> c 

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

while doing it using the for loop give the expected output

```
>>> a=[[0 for i in range(5+1)]for i in range(3+1)] 

>>> a

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

>>> a[1][4]=a[0][3]+1
>>>a

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

When you init `c` like this:

```
c=[[0]*5]*3
```

It is interpreted as such:

```
i = [0]*5
c = [i, i, i]
```

Which means that `c` is a list that is filled with a reference to the same object `i`.

So it doesn't matter which index of `c` you are accessing, it is actually the same instance (`i`).

In the second example:

```
a=[[0 for i in range(5+1)]for i in range(3+1)]
```

You are creating a new list for every index of the list. So you get the expected output.